# CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long Android studio 3.5.3

Tags: android

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugKotlin'.

  > java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\jre\bin\java": CreateProcess error=206, The filename or extension is too long
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s